# Rebuild webpack on production site

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Simple question that I cant seem to find an answer for. Im creating a static site generator with webpack. Is there any possible way that webpack can run and build the project again while on a production server? I'm guessing that I haven't been finding any information for a reason but I really want to know why.

Say my static site generator consumes data that is created using a CMS. When data is saved on the CMS I run a webpack build command and it rebuilds my served sites files. Is this possible or a really bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is only one way to do this. If you can generate your static site from console, you can add the command to the `scripts` section in `package.json` with webpack command like below:

```js
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "static-generator && webpack --config webpack.config.js",
  },
}
```

so, now you can run `npm run build` and you will get static version of the site and bundled js files.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I can build my site right now but the question is can I build it on the production server while the site is live and have it update?

Comment: i do not see problem with webpack, because webpack emit all files at once. But I think, git deploy is more right way, at least you can always switch back to previous version.